# Is the word language in this context a proper noun?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns, demonyms

My phrase is "Spanish language TV spend" with respect to advertising on Spanish language TV ads.

In this context, should the l in language be capitalized?

Comment: No. But the word _spend_ as a noun has a very limited usage; most people outside of advertising wouldn't understand it. Perhaps a better alternative is to treat _Spanish-language_ as a hyphenated compound noun, producing _Spanish-language TV spend_. That way you have two noun compounds (_TV_ is a compound; _tele-vision_ used to be hyphenated) modifying a nouned verb. Very MadAvSpeak.

Comment: Love the hyphenation. As I am currently on Madison Avenue in advertising, hopefully my colleagues will appreciate it!

Comment: If it's a title, you'll be able to find some guide saying you can capitalise John's hyphen.

Comment: I don't think language is a proper noun. Heree we're talking about the language spoken (originally) in Spain. Hence Spanish is a proper noun for that language. Also, English and German are languages and you wouldn't capitalize the plural. "Comparative Linguistics" as a title (book or class) might be a good counter-example.

Comment: Hence it may be said that Madison Avenue has devoted itself to the promotion of capitalism.

Comment: I'm wondering—if Madison Avenue has both words capitalized, what sets that apart from Spanish Language?  Is Spanish an adjective in this case?

Comment: No, it is not, and it should not be capitalized.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail?

Comment: Following up on @JohnLawler's comment: I suspect that more people will understand you if you replace "spend" with "expenditure". Other options: "expense", "cost", and "outlay".

Comment: True, but _expenditure_ (which _spend_ is obviously shortened from) costs three extra syllables, and it's not colloquial Adspeak.

Comment: @Scott you have to be careful with expenditure in business connotation because it suggests a capital expenditure, see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expenses_versus_Capital_Expenditures. Spend feels more correct than cost or expense, but evidently from the dictionary it isn't a noun.

Comment: YPCrumble: I think I understand what "expenditure" means. I may have misunderstood what you mean by "Spanish language TV spend". It sounds to me like "The money Company X spent on Spanish language TV ads". Since I'm not in advertising, I guess I'm just proving @John's point: "most people outside of advertising [won't] understand it (the word *spend* as a noun)."

Comment: In English, adjectives derived from proper nouns (except the names of characters in fictional works) usually retain their capitalization
– e.g. a Christian church, Canadian whisky, a Shakespearean sonnet, but not a quixotic mission, malapropism, holmesian nor pecksniffian.

Answer (score 1):

Following John Lawler's recommendation (in the comments above) to hyphenate "Spanish-language" would help readers grasp the intended meaning of the rather disjointed, noun-heavy string of words "Spanish language TV spend." Adding the hyphen might also weaken your impulse to (needlessly) capitalize *language*, since it tightens the visual connection of *Spanish* to *language* and emphasizes the subordinate relationship of *Spanish* to *language*.

So on the positive side, adding a hyphen improves the phrase's coherence. On the negative side, adding it introduces a little black line segment to the text—which many advertisers seem to dislike. The only explanation I've gotten from ad sales people who oppose this kind of clarifying hyphen is that hyphens "clog up" the wording and make it look "less open and inviting to readers." I don't find that to be true at all, but I suspect that an institutional prejudice against punctuation—even quite useful punctuation—lies behind some problematic open constructions that appear in ads.

Paradoxically the visually open, punctuation-free wording may tend to slow readers down as they try to figure out what word goes with what other word—and advertisers tend to like it when readers slow down while reading their ads. This, at any rate, is one possible explanation for the frequent absence of hyphens from ads in places where they would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the word language in this context a proper noun?

No, though it is arguably part of a proper name.

"The Spanish language" does after all denote an individual language. It differs from "The Spanish languages" which denote several (not just Castilian but also several other languages such as Aranese, Galician, Catalan, etc.) and "A Spanish language" which could mean any one of those.

> Should the l in language be capitalized?

No. If you were to accept that it was part of a proper name, you'd also accept that not all proper names are capitalised. You can use *summer* as a proper noun in saying "I hate summer", without capitalising it. (If you disagree that *summer* is a proper noun in such a use, you would indubitably disagree that "the Spanish language" is a proper name too, and so you wouldn't capitalise it either way).

I too, along with John and Sven, would suggest capitalising. Its worth considering, in the context of a site about English Language & Usage, what the usage is here.

The noun phrase *Spanish language* is, proper name or not, being used to modify another noun (*TV* as an abbreviation of *television*), forming a noun phrase which is further used to modify another noun (the jargon noun *spend*). (And presumably *Spanish language* is preferred over *Spanish* to differentiate this from the sense that would man television produced in Spain).

We do not hyphenate a combination of adjective and noun when used as an object or subject ("I do not speak the Spanish language", "The Spanish language has the second-highest number of native speakers"). When used as a modifier however, such hyphens are optional. Styles differ on how enthusiastic they are about such hyphens, but they can often offer clarity.