# Does one capitalize “Portuguese” when used in a hyphenated adjective?

Tags: adjectives, capitalization, hyphenation, compounds, demonyms

When *Portuguese* is used as part of a hyphenated adjective, does it take an initial capital letter? Just checking on this while proofreading an article.

#### Examples:

- **p**ortuguese-speaking college
- **P**ortuguese-based firm

Comment: I just [answered the same question for _Spanish-language TV spend_](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/186648/15299). The correct answer is as @phenry says -- it's _Portuguese-speaking._

Answer (score 6):

Names of languages are always capitalized in English, unlike in some other languages. This is true whether the name of the language is part of a compound or not.

Comment: ... and even more to the point, it has nothing to do with whether it's a language in the first place. We don't stop capitalizing Thursday, September, Jupiter, Moscow, BMW or Obama, either.

Answer (score -1):

Portuguese needs capital letter in this situation.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."